# How to find master node from worker node in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster

I need to know to which master node my current worker node is connected. I can see the worker nodes by typing "kubectl get nodes" command in the master node, but I need to find the master node from the worker node itself.

In simple words, How to find the master node from the worker node in the kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can usually find it on your `kubelet` config file: `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`

```
$ cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://1.1.1.1:6443 <== here
  name: default-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    namespace: default
    user: default-auth
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default-auth
  user:
    client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
    client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
```

If you have something like [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) you can get it like this:

```
yq .clusters[0].cluster.server /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf | tr -d "\n\""
```

Comment: it worked, I can able to find master's IP. but I've seen a comment(somewhere) which showed something like this "node IP: IP of worker(URL like address) master node running at master node's IP"

Comment: The kubelet file on GCP clusters is at `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig`. I found it by inspecting `/etc/default/kubelet`.

Answer (score 9):

When creating a cluster in GCP and then connect to that cluster with

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials kafka-and-zookeepr --zone us-central1-a --project {YOUR_PROJECT_NAME}
```

you can issue

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

This will return

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
GLBCDefaultBackend is running at https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/default-http-backend:http/proxy
Heapster is running at https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy
```

NOTE: I have docker installed on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

type

`kubectl get nodes -o wide`

and check the ROLES tab

Answer (score 0):

In case the Kubernetes cluster has a localhost nginx-proxy deployed, the accepted answer would return "localhost:port", effectively hiding the exact IP address from direct view. In order to retrieve the actual IP, first filter a container with `nginx-proxy`, then run `docker exec <container name> -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and watch the "upstream" section that corresponds to server section that listens on the displayed port.

An example: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf has `server: https://localhost:6443`, then `docker ps` displayed a pod named `k8s_nginx-proxy_nginx-proxy_STUFF` (shortened, random), and calling `docker exec k8s_nginx-proxy_nginx-proxy_STUFF -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` displayed the following output:

```
stream {
  upstream kube-apiserver {
    least_conn;
    server X.X.X.X:6443;
    server Y.Y.Y.Y:6443;
    ...
  }
  
  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:6443;
    proxy_pass kube_apiserver;
    ...
  }
}
```

This Nginx config causes all connections to localhost:6443 be streamed by TCP to a list of servers that are Kubernetes masters, or at least other proxies to K8S master servers, where you can continue searching.

PS: this config doesn't have kubectl on worker nodes, otherwise calling `kubectl get node` would result in displaying master nodes with their names or IPs right away. So, if someone would also have worket nodes with nginx-proxy for K8S master but no kubectl, this answer might be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

you may netstat -natp |grep kubelet to find the port also.

Answer (score -2):

execute command cat /etc/hosts it will give master node's IP