# How do I get a list of worker nodes associated to the same master node?

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for a way ***(Kubernetes API/Command)*** that returns a list of worker nodes associated to the same master node. I have been digging clues on Google for days but to no avail.

I have tried to look into details of every worker node using **"kubectl describe nodes"** but none of the options indicate any relationship between the worker node and master node.

I expect something like a list of Worker Node A, Worker Node B and Worker Node C returns when I input the common master node.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941015/how-to-find-master-node-from-worker-node-in-kubernetes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find master node from worker node in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941015/how-to-find-master-node-from-worker-node-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1):

In scenario with more than one master, the Kubernetes make leader selection so the other masters stays inactive.

You can use endpoints to check who the master is.

Comment: I have managed to get endpoints for pods but not nodes. Is there any other way that can retrieve similar info for nodes?

Comment: You can check this article https://medium.com/michaelbi-22303/deep-dive-into-kubernetes-simple-leader-election-3712a8be3a99