# How to get master server list from worker node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

i checked

```
cat  /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-client.conf
nslookup <apiServerEndpoint>
```

i get one master 
How to get other master details **lists**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941015/how-to-find-master-node-from-worker-node-in-kubernetes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find master node from worker node in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941015/how-to-find-master-node-from-worker-node-in-kubernetes)

Comment: could you write couple of more words? there are 4-5 ways of getting this info in 2 secs. What do you have? nslookup? nslookup what endpoint? you have a dns name resolving to your master node? why? are your masters behind a load balancer?

Comment: Did you had the opportunity to check if this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941015/how-to-find-master-node-from-worker-node-in-kubernetes) you? If not, please share more info as requested by @suren.